# Replace text (retaining special portion in the mid)

Tags: regex, emacs, cygwin

I want to

1. parse all files in a certain directory with the suffix ".org",
2. search in those files for text that starts with "[[outlook:" (like below)

   [[outlook:000000003730C053465F314590D066368CF3097B0700AAF83E03F96EDC42918E044642DEDDB3000013E2000E0000AAF83E03F96EDC42918E044642DEDDB3000013E2EFD30000][MESSAGE: RE: Subject of the Message (Sendername Senderfirstname) 2014-08-05 19:48]]
3. and then replace this text by
   [[\servername\path_path_path\path\Projects\outlook\000000003730C053465F314590D066368CF3097B0700AAF83E03F96EDC42918E044642DEDDB3000013E2000E0000AAF83E03F96EDC42918E044642DEDDB3000013E2EFD30000.msg][MESSAGE: RE: Subject of the Message (Sendername Senderfirstname) 2014-08-05 19:48]]

that means the "outlook:// shall be replaced by the serverpath, the long ID string (numbers and chars) must stay (this is different for each text which has to be replaced) and at the end of this ID, we must add ".msg".

I'm sorry, if this might be obvious and trivial for you, but I'm not yet familiar with regex and I don't know how to preserve the part in the middle (the ID string).

**NOTE:*

- there are also other similar chains with [[hyperlinkOrURL][text display of link]] which do NOT start with "outlook://" and which shall not be changed!
  So it is no option to just replace "outlook://" by the path and all "][" by ".msg][" for example
- I'm working with Windows 7, cygwin is installed and I have Emacs 24.3 to do this.

Comment: Basically, to preserve the part in the middle, you need to pattern match and use the match. You can search the regexp `outlook:\([0-9A-Z]\)` and replace it with `path\1`, where `\1` refers to the match from the parenthesis `\(...\)`. See also that doc: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElispCookbook#toc34

Comment: An idea: to do it interactively, without writing lisp code, use rgrep and writable grep (https://github.com/mhayashi1120/Emacs-wgrep). Then you can use `query-replace-regexp` in the grep buffer and use the construct I explained before. You can even use `M-x re-builder` to check your regexp interactively !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have cygwin installed, you might want to give the command-line a chance, it is much better suited for the job than Emacs.

```bash
find <directory> -maxdepth 1 -name "*.org" -exec sed -i 's|^\[\[outlook:\([^]]*\)|[[\\servername\\path_path_path\\path\\Projects\\outlook\\\1.msg|' {} \;
```

Note that while your question mentions the string `outlook://` your actual example does not have the double-slashes after the word "outlook:", so I didn't include those in the regular expression. Feel free to add them if that was a mistake.

Also note that when inserting the actual server path, you have to write double-backslash for every backslash of your path: this is because a backslash is used as an escape character here, as you can see, for example, in the initial `[[`. The brackets have to be escaped because `[` and `]` have a [special meaning in regular expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html).

The `sed` command has the following form `'s|<regex>|<replacement>|'` i.e., the regular expression and the replacement are enclosed in pipe characters `|`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:
find: ([[outlook:)([0-9A-Z]*)(][)(.*)(]])
replace: [[path\outlook\\2.msg\3\4\5

Refer to [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/oN8oE3/1)

Comment: Thanks, I'm stilly trying to get rid of the errors. IT does not work yet. In Emacs it seems that I have to write the ] and [ at least in the query string with \[, but not in the replace string ...